# AJAX Call - Does not recognize WP_Query

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

i have Ajax call for getting response , in response file i have used wordpress loop And Get This Error :
Fatal error: Class 'wp_query' not found ....

i want to show Some Special Page Content in some div in Index.php and Return Result with Ajax to index.php

Here :

```
   <script>
myfunc = function()
{           
    $("#target").slideUp(300);
    $("#target").slideDown(300,"swing",function()
        {                           
            splittedURL=window.location.href.split("#");
            $.post('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/page.php','state='+splittedURL[1],function(data,status)
            {
                $("#target").html(data);
            })      
        }
    );                          
}
</script>
```

and Here Page :

```
<?php
$state=$_POST["state"];
switch ($state) {
    case "2755":
        echo "<b>Ok 1<b/>";
        break;
    case "2756":
        echo "<b>Ok 2/b>";
        break;    
    default:
  ?>
  <!-- Page Load -->
 <div id="panel-box" class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="col-md-12 panel-heading">
  <?php
    $my_query = new WP_Query('page_id=$state');
    while ($my_query->have_posts()):
    $my_query->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>
    <h3 class="col-md-11 panel-title p-m"><?php the_title();?></h3>
    <div class="col-md-1 close p-m" onClick="$('#panel-box').slideUp(500)">X</div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body">
<?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<!-- End Page Load -->
 </div>

  <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Is `wp-includes/query.php` included in the ajax page before you call `wp_query`?

Comment: No , Must be Included ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find This Code :

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);  
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

it must define in page and load wp functions.

Comment: Note that the path for `wp-load.php` can vary based on where your file is, but this is the right idea and the concept worked for me.